# FOR Loop in Robot Framework failing to click through elements

Tags: robotframework, ui-automation

I'm trying to create a FOR Loop in Robot Framework that will click through a set of links on a page. Trying to avoid a string of "Click Element" lines and just make a loop out of it. I believe my base code is correct in the loop construction, but PyCharm is seeing the first line of the loop as its own keyword, which isn't right. It's not moving past that part. Any ideas here?

My variables are known, just stored off on another file.

````
Documentation       Homepage
Library             Zoomba.GUILibrary
Library             Process
Resource            ../../Pages/resource.robot
Suite Setup         Browser Setup  ${url}

*** Keywords ***

Menu Navigation
    ${list}=  Create List       ${TUAbout}  ${TUAcademics}  ${TUResearch}
        :FOR ${item} IN @{list}
            Wait For And Click Element  ${item}
        END

*** Test Cases ***

TC 001 Menu Navigation
    Menu Navigation```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need at least 2 spaces for the variables on the FOR line and FOR syntax has changed in more recent versions of RF so :FOR is deprecated syntax use just FOR e.g.

```
FOR  ${item}  IN  @{list}
```

I believe that should be enough to fix the current error you're seeing